# How to connect to sql server to PHP for remote connection

Tags: php, sql-server, database

I have use this code but not connect to sql serve for remote connection and error is fire.I get this error:

```
Couldn't connect to SQL Server on XX.XXX.XX.XX
```

code:

```
<?php
$myServer = "XX.XXX.XX.XX";
$myUser = "New";
$myPass = "123";
$myDB = "Live"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
  or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); 

//select a database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
  or die("Couldn't open database $myDB"); ?>
```

What does this error message?

Comment: Your provider may not allow you to do so

Comment: What does mssql_get_last_message() say? Execute this after mssql_connect in die function or instead of die.

Comment: Are you sure that user allowed connection from `ANY` ? Because default is `localhost`. There is possibility firewall things.

Comment: @krutssss : is this your another account?

Comment: @ krzysiej, couldnot show in any messages or error .

Comment: @Colour Dalnet, How we can check  firewall issue

Comment: Wait, this is SQL Server? Do you really know how to connect PHP with SQL Server? Have you try to connect it using `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio` using remote connection?

Comment: @Colour Dalnet,  Yes, Actually i have connected in host gator server it works, But now i am trying to connect in godaddy server its not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70032/discussion-between-colour-dalnet-and-samarth).

Answer (score 1):

First try to telnet port on remote server, by default it's 3306. 
If you can't access this port it's probably not allowed on firewall or the mysql server isn't listening to remote connections.

Then check mysql settings on server, by default it's accessible only from localhost. On linux servers it's usually in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
just comment this line:

```
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

Then check authorization of the user that you use for a login, note that you need both authorization to log in from where you are now and authorization to log in on the server (as localhost) as well..

Example from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html :

```
CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
WITH GRANT OPTION;

CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

creates a user with username "monty" and password "some_pass" with all privileges on all tables in all databases `(*.*)`
 from anywhere(`localhost` and `%` - as any ip).

Comment: please explain in details?

Comment: Its working in host gator sever. but not working in go daddy server

Comment: added some details, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Couldn't connect to SQL Server

Comment: or die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer"); this is what throws your error and it's because mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass) fails. and it fails because either there's no connection to server, port isn't open or accessible, or user is not authorized to enter.

Comment: please explain more details

Comment: unless you tell me what did you try and was the outcome or at least which part you don't understand, i can't really specify.